# I Cannot go to page on wwwroot ASP.NET & React.js

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a problem with my project. 
Before I describe it, I'll write my road to publish:
First I run build frontend project (*react*), and put build file to wwwroot (*.NET Core Web Api*).
 When all is ready (backend and frontend in one solution) i send to server. 
Now, when i go to home page and login, register everythings is ok. Problem is when i try going to page after login (when I'm not logged), or go to the confirmation email page, browser show me a *not found page* error.
Also when i run only build folder all page are working, and when I go to page after login (when I'm not logged), app redirects me to login page.
Under is my startup code:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();


            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

       }
}
```

Do you have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some routes like this:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(
            options =>
            {
                foreach (var description in apiProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                }
            });
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "api",
                template: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: it,s not working :/
still show me then page not exists. Look on this:
[link](http://api.beta.kimmi.pl/confirm-account/d97fed20-1e3a-40b5-9dd9-144ce8c32a8c)
I added this line on you wrote

Comment: @matgorzynski try with new changes pls.

Comment: no, but when i create project .net core + react & redux, and copy my all code its working, but there swagger not working :/

Comment: @matgorzynski need to review swagger configuration for fix it, and try add new changes pls.